# python datetime convert, dates may contains whitespaces

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have a .csv file with a date column, and the date looks like this.

```
date
2016年 4月 1日   <-- there are whitespaces in thie row
...
2016年10月10日
```

The date format is Japanese date format. I'm trying to convert this column to 'YYYY-MM-DD', and the python code I'm using is below.

```
data['date'] = [datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y年%m月%d日').date() for d in data['date']]
```

There is one problem, the date column in the .csv may contain **whitespace** when the month/day is a single digit. And my code doesn't work well when there is a whitespace.

Anyone solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pandas is best avoid list comprehension if exist vectorized solutions because performance and no support `NaN`s.

I think need [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) by `\s+` : one or more whitespaces with [`pandas.to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) for converting to datetimes and last for dates add [`date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html):

```
data['date'] = (pd.to_datetime(data['date'].str.replace('\s+', ''), format='%Y年%m月%d日')
                  .dt.date)
```

**Performance**:

The plot was created with [perfplot](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot):

[image: df]

```
def list_compr(df):
    df['date1'] = [datetime.datetime.strptime(d.replace(" ", ""), '%Y年%m月%d日').date() for d in df['date']]
    return df

def vector(df):
    df['date2'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str.replace('\s+', ''), format='%Y年%m月%d日').dt.date)
    return df

def make_df(n):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2016年 4月 1日','2016年10月10日']}) 
    df = pd.concat([df] * n, ignore_index=True)
    return df

perfplot.show(
    setup=make_df,
    kernels=[list_compr, vector],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(2, 13)],
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    equality_check=False,  # rows may appear in different order
    xlabel='len(df)')
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Python actually, but wouldn't something like replacing `d` in `strptime` with `d.replace(" ", "")` do the trick?